# characters getting appended in StringBuilder List

Tags: java

I am newbie to java programming. I am working on program to generate all possible combinations of given characters with given length.

For example if a=3 and b=2 means 3 characters will be there and word length has to be 2.

**So possible combinations will be aa,ab,ac,ba,bb,bc,ca,cb,cc.**

I have written program in java but it is having some problem as it is appending previous sting to new character.
Can somebody guide, what is wrong here?

My Program:

```
package com.practice.programs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProgramClass {

    public static int getWords(int a, int b) {

        int charCount = a, wordLength = b, halfCount = a / 2;
        // Not sure whether one needs to declare this ugly array. :(
        char[] charArray = { '@', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
                'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };


        List<StringBuilder> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();
        List<StringBuilder> newUniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();


        /**
         * lets start with formation of all combinations of words.
         * I know this is ugly approach. :(
         */

        for(int i=0;i<wordLength;i++){

            if(uniqueWords.size()!=0){
                for(int k=0;k< uniqueWords.size();k++){
                    for(int j=0;j<charCount;j++){
                        StringBuilder tempWord = uniqueWords.get(k);
                        tempWord.append(String.valueOf(charArray[j+1]));
                        System.out.println(tempWord);
                        newUniqueWords.add(tempWord);
                    }
                }
                uniqueWords.clear();
                uniqueWords = newUniqueWords;
                newUniqueWords.clear();
            }
            else{
                for(int j=0;j<charCount;j++){
                    uniqueWords.add(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(charArray[j+1])));
                }
            }           
        }

        // print all combinations of words

        for (StringBuilder stringBuilder : uniqueWords) {
            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        }

        return uniqueWords.size();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int a = 3, b = 2;
        System.out.println(getWords(a, b));
    }
}
```

It prints output as

```
 aa
 aab
 aabc
 ba
 bab
 babc
 ca
 cab
 cabc
 0
```

Please help here.

Comment: This is more like a algorithm problem

Comment: [This](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41510/calculate-all-possible-combinations-of-given-characters) question is very similar than what you want,